# Extract data from an xml fragment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, xml, parse

In SQL Server 2014, I have the following xml fragment :

```
<salesorder>
   <ordnum>123</ordnum>
   <orddate>2017-04-17</orddate>
   <details>
      <detail>
         <itemtype>Stationery</itemtype>
         <itemdesc>Pencil</itemdesc>
         <specifications>
            <specification>
               <name>Qty</name>
               <value>5</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Description</name>
               <value>Pencil H1</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Price</name>
               <value>1.50</value>
            </specification>
         </specifications>
      </detail>
      <detail>
         <itemtype>Stationery</itemtype>
         <itemdesc>Pencil</itemdesc>
         <specifications>
            <specification>
               <name>Qty</name>
               <value>10</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Description</name>
               <value>Pencil H2</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Colour</name>
               <value>Red</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Price</name>
               <value>2.75</value>
            </specification>
         </specifications>
      </detail>
   </details>
</salesorder>
```

I would like to extract the following data :

```
ordnum   itemtype     qty   price
123      Stationery   5     1.50
123      Stationery   10    2.75
```

Is this possible to accomplish in T-SQL?

Thanks in advance,
MP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your XML in the variable `@X`:

```
select @X.value('(salesorder/ordnum/text())[1]', 'int') as ordnum,
       T.X.value('(itemtype/text())[1]', 'varchar(15)') as itemtype,
       T.X.value('(specifications/specification[name/text() = "Qty"]/value/text())[1]', 'int') as qty,
       T.X.value('(specifications/specification[name/text() = "Price"]/value/text())[1]', 'money') as price
from @X.nodes('/salesorder/details/detail') as T(X);
```

The most complicated part of this query is probably the XQuery expression used to get the values for `Qty` and `Price`.

`[name/text() = "Qty"]` is a predicate that looks at the value for the node `name` and returns true if it is `Qty`.

The rest is basic XML query stuff using [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) to shred the XML on `/salesorder/details/detail` to get one row per detail element and [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) to extract the values you want from your XML.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses!  Although both responses gave the desired results, Mikael's solution was more elegant and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Below t-sql code will surely help you.

```
DECLARE @vXML XML;
SET @vXML = '<salesorder>
   <ordnum>123</ordnum>
   <orddate>2017-04-17</orddate>
   <details>
      <detail>
         <itemtype>Stationery</itemtype>
         <itemdesc>Pencil</itemdesc>
         <specifications>
            <specification>
               <name>Qty</name>
               <value>5</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Description</name>
               <value>Pencil H1</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Price</name>
               <value>1.50</value>
            </specification>
         </specifications>
      </detail>
      <detail>
         <itemtype>Stationery</itemtype>
         <itemdesc>Pencil</itemdesc>
         <specifications>
            <specification>
               <name>Qty</name>
               <value>10</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Description</name>
               <value>Pencil H2</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Colour</name>
               <value>Red</value>
            </specification>
            <specification>
               <name>Price</name>
               <value>2.75</value>
            </specification>
         </specifications>
      </detail>
   </details>
</salesorder>';
```

```
SELECT  
       salesorder.Col.value('ordnum[1]', 'int') 
       , detail.Col.value('itemtype[1]', 'varchar(255)')
       , specification_qty.Qty AS Qty
       , specification_price.Price AS Price
FROM @vXML.nodes('//salesorder') AS salesorder(Col)
    CROSS APPLY salesorder.Col.nodes('details') AS details(Col)
    CROSS APPLY details.Col.nodes('detail') AS detail(Col)
    CROSS APPLY detail.Col.nodes('specifications') AS specifications(Col)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT specification.Col.value('value[1]', 'int') AS Qty FROM specifications.Col.nodes('specification') AS specification(Col) WHERE specification.Col.value('name[1]','VARCHAR(255)') = 'Qty') AS specification_qty
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT specification.Col.value('value[1]', 'decimal(3,2)') AS Price FROM specifications.Col.nodes('specification') AS specification(Col) WHERE specification.Col.value('name[1]','VARCHAR(255)') = 'Price') AS specification_price
```

**Little description about the solution:**

As the provided XML is a multilevel XML, we will need to process the data in chunk. Hence we need to segregate the multiple levels of xmls in multiple tables and then cross apply them to get the required result. If it was a single level XML data then a single `SELECT * FROM Tbl` method could have worked.

Reference Links:

[Single level XML solution provided by Sanchitos on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989395/convert-xml-to-table-sql-server)

[Multilevel XML solution provided by George T on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650121/parsing-a-multilevel-xml-in-sql-server)

[Query XML in SQL Server for Different Hierarchy Levels using Cross Apply](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/xml-in-sql-server-hierarchy-levels-cross-apply.aspx)

Hope this will help.